# MapboxGL weird border won't go away

Tags: css, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a React app with a MapboxGL component. I am having trouble removing the gray border surrounding my map (see picture below).

[image]

I've played around with the Map.css as shown below

```
.map-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: rgba(35, 55, 75, 0.9);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-family: monospace;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20;
  left: 20;
  margin: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.mapboxgl-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

but I'm not sure why the border is still present even after setting everything to 0.

I think it is due to the required import per the Mapbox API `import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, I needed to add `width: 100vw;` to the `.map-container` section in my css file. Silly mistake on my part!